# why the default select drop list doesn't change?

Tags: javascript

```
<form method="get" action="http://example.com/" name="currencies">
<div>
Currencies:

<select  onchange="this.form.submit();" class="select" name="currency">
  <option value="USD" selected="selected">US Dollar</option>
  <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
  <option value="GBP">GB Pound</option>
  <option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar</option>
  <option value="AUD">Australian Dollar</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" value="index" name="main_page"/>                           
</div>
</form>
```

when i select the `GB Pound`, all the function is ok except that the default selected is still `US Dollar`.when i delete the `selected="selected"` in `<option value="USD"..`. when i change to `Australian Dollar`. the item shows on the select drop list is still US Dollar. why?

Comment: If there is no "selected" at all, the UI will show the first one as selected.

Comment: how to set the selected item to the one which i choosed?eg:when i choose Canadian Dollar. the UI shows Canadian Dollar not the first one?

Comment: _"except that the default selected is still US Dollar"_ - do you mean if you view the source, or what? (Because View / Source will show what the browser received from the webserver, not the current state of the page.) How are you determining what the "default selected" is after changing the selection? If you change the selection and submit the form are you getting the correct value at the server?

Comment: When does it do that? After the page has reloaded (with the results of the form submission)? If so, that would be new HTML, so you could place the selected attribute somewhere else. Maybe server-side or with Javascript onReady.

Comment: yeah, i viewed the source. i don't know how to determine what the "default selected" is after changing the selection?

Comment: when change the selection and submit the form i can get the correct value ?

Answer (score 1):

The "default" selection applies when the page first loads, and will be either the option with the "selected" attribute, or the first option when none were specified as "selected".

The View Source facility shows what the browser originally received from the webserver, *not* the current state of everything on the page after the user (or JavaScript) has changed things.

If you use JavaScript to get values of fields (e.g., in response to some user action) the current values will be reported.

When you submit the form, the *current* values of your form fields will be sent to the web server and can be accessed by your server-side code.

If the result of submitting the form is to redisplay the same page and you want the previously selected option to still be selected then you should use server-side code to apply the "selected" attribute to the appropriate option. What server-side technology are you using? PHP? (Or JSP, .NET, ...?)

Comment: do u konw why phplist.xxmn.com/dvd this site can work? the change currency is located on the right top of the page.

Comment: php, the programme i use is zencart

Answer (score 0):

When you choose "Australian Dollar" the action url will have "currency=AUD" but the HTML code itself does not change. The selected="selected" still stays with the US Dollar.

You could use some simple jQuery to move the selected attribute if you like in the DOM, but if you refresh the page, you will still have the same, original HTML you started with.

Comment: do u konw why http://phplist.xxmn.com/dvd/ this site can work? the change currency is located on the right top of the page.

Comment: They are using a server side language such as PHP to save the option that is selected.

Comment: Zencart is built on top of the programming language PHP. So if you [learn a little PHP](http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Editing_PHP) you could have the same functionality.